# In linux if watchdog manager is not kicked by a process is it a reset or reboot

Tags: linux, embedded-linux, watchdog

In embedded Linux if we register a process to the watchdog manager and if the process didn't kick the watchdog manager then what happens, is it a **reset** or **reboot**.

Is the watchdog mentioned generally in Linux a software watchdog.

I am a novice in Linux. Please pardon me if i am asking any blunder...

Comment: This is documented in [`Documentation/watchdog/watchdog-api.txt`](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/watchdog/watchdog-api.txt).

Comment: Every where its written as the system is rebooted and not reseted. So it should actually be a software watchdog right.

Comment: If you need to monitor your service, look at [monit](http://mmonit.com/monit/). Btw reset and reboot in the language of [watchdog](http://linux.die.net/man/8/watchdog) is the same. And take close look at [systemd](http://patrakov.blogspot.de/2011/01/writing-systemd-service-files.html).

Comment: @yegorich That link with watchdog was very helpful, so basically there are both type of watchdog... software and hardware and which one we need to use depends on our need right...